# Install a Greasemonkey script Tor Linux via Bash

Tags: linux, bash, tor

I would like to install a Greasemonkey script to Tor. Without any GUI interaction.

[a link](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/install-a-greasemonkey-script-from-a-local-file/)

I don't mind the local server technique but still dont want any GUI interaction.

Comment: So, where are you stuck? Provide a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that link is really just useless now 
wget https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/1865/addon-1865-latest.xpi
firefox -silent -install-global-extension addon-1865-latest.xpi -setDefaultBrowser www.google.es